# How do you find cardinality of the set of functions $A\to A$? How to take the first step to approach this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $A$ is set with $10$ elements and $|A| = 10$:

$1)$ $|\{f \;|\; f: A \to A \text{ is a function}\}|=$

$2)$ $|\{f \;|\; f: A \to A \text{ is a bijective function}\}|=$

Comment: I don't get it :\

Answer (score 2):

**HINT.**

$1.$ To be a function, you need to know what to do with each element. For instance, if I ask you what $f(1)$ is, you have to be able to tell me. Call these $10$ elements the numbers $1$, $2$, ... , $10$. How many options do you have for $f(1)$? $f(2)$? Etc. How many total functions do you then have?

$2$. You now need the function to be bijective. So you need eventually need to choose each number $1$, ... , $10$ at least once (so that $f$ is surjective). But once you choose a number for $f(\text{something})$, you cannot choose it again (so that $f$ is injective). Let's just do this in order. How many options for $f(1)$? Given your choice for $f(1)$, how many options for $f(2)$? Repeat. How many total bijections then do you have?

Comment: So $$|\{f \;|\; f: A \to A \text{ is a function}\}|$$ means that a set containing f(a) where a is an element of the set A?

Then isn't both question 1 and 2 size 10? 
Because $$|{f(a_1), f(a_2), f(a_3), f(a_4)... f(a_10 )}| = 10$$

Comment: @TaeCoda No. Try this with a smaller set, say $|A|=3$. Let's call the elements of $A$ the letters $x$, $y$, $z$. Define $f$ by $f(x)=x$, $f(y)=y$, $f(z)=z$. That's a perfectly reasonable function, it's the identity function! How about $f(x)=x$, $f(y)=x$, $f(z)=x$. That's a function isn't it?! It's a constant function! Notice to be a function, you need to know what 'to do' with an element. So $f(x)=\{x,y\}$ is not allowed. Then given a potential function $f$, how many choices are there for $f(x)$? What about $f(y)$? What about $f(z)$?

Comment: @TaeCoda For the second part, let's try to define a bijection, using the same notation as in my previous comment. How about $f(x)=y$. Now what to do with $f(y)$? Would $f(y)=y$ work? No, because then the function would not be injective. So $f(y)=x$ or $f(y)=z$. Why not $f(y)=z$. Then what about $f(z)$? Well, $f(z)=y$ won't work since $f(x)=y$. Moreover, $f(z)=z$ won't work since $f(y)=z$. Then we are forced to choose $f(z)=x$. So suppose you had a bijection $f$, how many choices for $f(x)$? Given $f(x)$, how many for $f(y)$? Then what about $f(z)$? How many choices does this leave?

Comment: @TaeCoda Finally, if all this gives you trouble, with my same example and notation, the set is small enough that you could write down every function and every bijection explicitly. Perhaps that would give you more insight into how all this is working. I would not try it with the $10$ case! You'll find that would take quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, just a recommendation of a way of looking at things.

When I was a wee lad, mathematically speaking, people denoted the set of maps from a set $A$ to a set $B$ as $B^A$. Try it on some small sets, especially with $|A|=1$ and $|A|=2$.

As to the bijective functions $A$ to $A$, just write them all down, for $A=\{1,2,3\}$. What have you done? You’ve written down all permutations of $A$. Now do you see why my childhood teachers wrote $A!$ ?

Now for an exercise: find the cardinality of the set of all permutations of the natural numbers $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \{a_1, \dots, a_{10}\}$, and $f: A \to A$ be a bijection.  Notice that if we list $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{10})$, then since $f$ is a bijection $(f(a_1), f(a_2), \dots, f(a_{10}))$ is just a rearrangement of $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{10})$.  So you are counting the number of ways you can rearrange $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{10})$ (keeping in mind that doing nothing is also a rearrangement).